# What does o b Dr. mean in a Rode Caprice #5?

Tags: terminology, violin, bowing

[image]

What does o b Dr. mean in this Caprice?

Comment: Obviously it means part must be played by a licensed obstetrician (sorry)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check the beginning of the book. It stands for *oberes Drittheil*, or using the upper third of the bow. Note, these suggestions of bow usage are by the editor Emil Kroll. Personally, for modern technique, I'm a fan of Galamian's edition, but if you want to do the historical research you can also go straight to [Rode's original](https://imslp.org/wiki/24_Caprices_for_Solo_Violin%2C_Op.22_(Rode%2C_Pierre)). Note that the numbering is totally different in that first edition, though.

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it. Note that the 1/3 bow indication is actually given above the staff. Apparently OP's edition has both English and German instructions.

Comment: @Aaron Yup, one of those cluttered bilingual approaches

Comment: FWIW in modern German it's _oberes Drittel._